# .addClass with animated css3 menu

Tags: jquery, html

My css3 animated menu is working pretty well. But now i want to add some `selected` class to him.

but i dont know how to implement with the css3 animation.

i have try this:

```
$('#menu a').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).addClass("selected");
            var h = $(this).attr('href');
            $("#conteudo").fadeOut("slow", function() {
                $(this).html($(h).html()).fadeIn("slow");
            });
        });
```

But is not working. I have made this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8L797/

Comment: In what way is the `css3 animation` presenting a problem? What part are you stuck with?

Comment: @DavidThomas when i click on menu, i need to stop the animation of `em` element on `top:0` and `span` element on `top:100%` but i dont know what i need to setup this.. if you see my Fiddle, on CSS tab, you see my `.selected`class.. but this not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the `selected` class and I also made the click event remove the class from existing links.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/TNzuH/

CSS:

```
#menu a.selected span,
#menu a.selected:hover span {
    top: -100%;
}
#menu a.selected em,
#menu a.selected:hover em {
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You had some errors in your code, like not closing your jQuery function.  Also, it looks like your styles apply to the LI tag, not the A tag, so you'll want to add the class to the LI.  Check out my [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8L797/1/) and see if you can work with that.

Comment: first, thanks for your help, this works fine, but, when i click in another `link` the first i have clicked keep clicked. There is a way to add `.removeClass` to that?

Comment: I suggest .toggleClass(). @Preston

Comment: Yes, you can remove the class from all of them and then add it back to the one that you clicked - http://jsfiddle.net/8L797/3/